# Infinite Digest when Mocking $location

Tags: angularjs, testing, mocking

I've discovered that if I try to mock Angular's $location service and then I need to force any sort of digest in my test then I get an infinite digest error.  It doesn't matter what the code is in my controller.  I have tried this with a completely empty controller which just takes $location as a parameter and if I then do a digest in my test at all it fails.

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jmcooper/wzAyL/58/) and here's my test from that fiddle:

```
describe('fooController', function() {
    var controller, mocklocation, scope;

    beforeEach(function() {
        module("myModule");

        inject(function($rootScope, $controller, $location) {
            scope = $rootScope.$new();

            mocklocation = sinon.stub($location);
            controller = $controller("FooController", { $scope: scope, $location: location });
        });
    });

    describe('when calling $digest in a test', function () {
        beforeEach(function () {
            //do some stuff here and then resolve a promise

            //call digest to cause the resolved promise to get evaluated
            scope.$root.$digest();
        });
        it('should not get infinite digests', function () {

        });
    });
});
```

Notice that all I'm doing is a scope.$root.$digest in that test.  In my real code I was resolving a promise before that digest so that's why I needed to do the digest.

Comment: Can you share the code that requires a digest.  What kind of promise would require a root digest?

Comment: I can add some things to the code for clarity if needed, but the code itself doesn't need a digest.  I am resolving a promise inside my jasmine test and for Angular to process that promise.resolve(), I have to call digest in my test.

Comment: Not if the promise is generated by `$http` then you would use `$httpBackend`.  That is why it would be good to see what promise you are having to resolve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to mock the entire $location service, I suggest you hand-roll your own mock and stub only the thing you need to test. For example, if you are using the mockLocation to assert that the path function is called with a particular path, you could set up your mock like this:

```
mockLocation = { path: sinon.stub() };
```

and then you can still assert the same thing like this:

```
expect(mockLocation.path.calledWith(...)).toBeTruthy();
```

I'm not sure why stubbing the whole object causes an infinite digest (those are so tricky!) but this should at least allow you to move forward. Also, in your test make sure you send in the mockLocation object when you inject it (right now you have "$location: location").

```
 controller = $controller("FooController", { $scope: scope, $location: mockLocation });
```